# Any tool that can do partial code generation based on javabean rules(setter and getter method)

Tags: properties, code-generation, javabeans

Say if I have a class in java and I want it to be a javabean(those getter and setter methods)

The class that I write:

```
class MyClass{
    String var1;
    Integer var2;
    ........
    many other properties
    ........
}
```

After partial code generation based on javabean rules:(If there is some tool!)

```
class MyClass{
    String var1;
    Integer var2;
    ........
    many other properties
    ........

    public void setVar1(String var1){
       this.var1=var1;
    }
    public String getVar1(){
       return var1;
    }

    public void setVar2(Integer var2){
       this.var1=var1;
    }

    public Integer getVar2(){
       return var2;
    }
    ............
    Many other getter and setter method
    ............
}
```

It is very tedious to have to write all those getter and setter methods for all the properties in order to make **MyClass** a javabean.

Is there any **software or IDE plugin** that can help do the rest of the work as long as I just give the properties. Even though some of the assumingly-generated code is not correct, but modifying just some of the generated code is much faster and delightful than having to write those codes on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any IDE worth the name will do this for you.  For example, in Eclipse it's right-click > Source -> Getters and Setters.

Different in other IDEs, obviously, but they do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse & Netbeans and perhaps other IDE's have a "generate getters and setters"-shortcut.